# PGN format and comments with tag pairs

Tags: pgn, annotation

Currently making a parser for PGN files. And wondering if there is any practice of using commentary in Tag pair section, like:

[Event "Tournament X"];hosted once a year

[Event "Tournament X"]{hosted once a year}

Has anyone seen such PGN? Is it used? Cause I couldn't find no such clause in PGN standart that forbids such comments. Or it's me that's just blind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is invalid in PGN, please don't do that. Your second example is also invalid. We don't put comment to the same line as the header.

Comment: thx for the clarification